# Replacing dry white wine with bubbly

Tags: substitutions, wine

I have an onion soup recipe that calls for dry white wine.

Can I replace the dry white wine with simple white cava/lambrusco?

**NOTE:** I'm aware that there are a number questions regarding substitution of wine, but they seem to refer to non-alcoholic substitutes so none of them mention alcholic alternatives.

Comment: I like to use cheap cider I stead of wine altogether :)

Comment: Lambrusco is a red sparkling wine, so it would not work at all, it will change the savor of the dish.

Comment: @max [not always](https://www.google.com/search?q=lambrusco+bianco)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not mind using a Cava in the Brut range.  To me that would be like substituting hints of pears with hints of green apples. French onion soup can be made with different stocks, so I am assuming you are using a chicken stock recipe, which typically calls for a dry white wine.  If you are using a beef or veal stock, a low sugar Lambrusco may work, but I can't imagine the flavor.

I use the wine while frying the onions (and not just in the recipe :-).  The alcohol helps creates new flavors and it also dissolves some extra ingredients. I find the resulting flavor is richer.  As the onions are just as important as the broth, I like the technique Kenji López-Alt's [developed after frying 20 lbs of onions](http://bit.ly/1id14Os).  Dashes of wine add sugar and water as he suggests (one can skip the baking soda part for the soup).

With the French onion soup I like Pinot Gris, which reminds me of pears, green tea, and lemons and is not too sweet, with under 12 grams of sugar per liter.  I find that the wine flavor does not blend if it is too sweet.  The flavors of a Cava are more green apples and spices and their sweetness levels can vary dramatically.  They go *Brut Nature*, *Extra Brut*, *Brut*, and *Extra Dry*, with the extra dry being the sweetest with 12 to 17 grams of sugar per liter.

Comment: Nice and comprehensive answer. I was mostly worried by the fact that Cava/Lambrusco are carbonated and wasn't sure what effect this would have.